# Copy link from one div and paste in other div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a recurring html. I want to copy link from first anchor and place inside a span tag here is my HTML

```
<li class="clearfix">
   <div class="latest_post_text_inner">
      <h5 class="latest_post_title ">
          <a href="first link which I want to copy">test</a>
      </h5>
      <span class="post_infos">here I want to place first link</span>
   </div>
</li>
<li class="clearfix">
   <div class="latest_post_text_inner">
      <h5 class="latest_post_title ">
          <a href="second link which I want to copy">test</a>
      </h5>
      <span class="post_infos">here I want to place second link</span>
   </div>
</li>
```

This HTML is generating from a plugin and I'm not able to edit that plugin. I want to copy this url through j Query.

I have found the solution of this issue. Here is the code which is worked for me

```
jQuery('.latest_post_text_inner').each(function(){ 
    var _linkUrl = jQuery(this).find('.latest_post_title a').attr('href');
    jQuery(this).find('.post_infos').text(_linkUrl);
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? This can be done with one fairly simple jquery function and isn't difficult. People are here to help with code that isn't working...not write code from scratch for you

Answer (score 0):

*This is an edit of an earlier post to make it scaleable as pointed out in comments*

```
var titles = document.getElementsByClassName("latest_post_title");
var infos = document.getElementsByClassName("post_infos");
for(var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++)
{
   infos.item(i).href = titles.item(i).href;
}
```

Quite simply just gets each of a class and sets the infos class to titles class.

Comment: This is not a scaleable answer. Using ID is not needed whereas a loop is

Comment: @charlietfl I assume that this is what you meant then?

Comment: definitely more appropriate

Comment: boo boo though...need href's and `slides` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution of this issue. Here is the code which is worked for me

```
jQuery('.latest_post_text_inner').each(function(){ 
    var _linkUrl = jQuery(this).find('.latest_post_title a').attr('href');
    jQuery(this).find('.post_infos').text(_linkUrl);
});
```